# How to configure Glassfish to allocate different memory size for JVM per web application

Tags: memory-usage, glassfish, jvm

I have 2 Java web applications deployed on my **Glassfish Enterprise Server v2.1.1**.

I want each of them to have different configurations for JVM options, specially for memory allocation. I have studied [this](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/04/glassfish-performance-tunning/) document. But it contains approach for specifying JVM options at the entire server level, while I want to do the same at application level.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

PS: I'm not a system engineer but whatever suggestion I receive, I'll try to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify memory options for the application that satisfy both applications, then you need to run multiple instances of your container.

This will give you 2 JVMs with different run time options, but also the overhead of running another glassfish instance.

Sadly for you, memory management are per JVM and thus per server instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to achieve this thing with multiple domain creation and each application running on different domain?